# Is this program having any sequence point issues?

Tags: c++, c, operator-precedence

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [twisted c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187405/twisted-c-code)
>   [FAQ : Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/faq-undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {  
       int i=7,j;
       j=(i++,++i,j*i); 
       return 0;
}
```

Is `j=(i++,++i,j*i++);` well defined ? Let me clear my doubt.

Comment: You guys have the same homework? Possible duplicate of [twisted c++ code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187405/twisted-c-code)

Comment: Yes both `j=(i++,++i,j*i); ` and `j=(i++,++i,j*i++);` are [well defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/faq-undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Comment: It has a problem, in that the average reader will not have a clue as to what is the intent of this code. Usually, if you write code that can be read by humans, it won't have issues for the compiler either.

Comment: It might be the same overall assignment.  But the actual code (and answer) is different.  This is well-defined, but "twisted" is not, because it modifies `j` twice without an intervening sequence point.